Getting Error when try to enable bcmath extension on heroku using composer.json file
I am trying to enable bcmath php extension on heroku using composer.json file as per documentation instructions article.
When try to build i got error

remote:   Problem 1


remote:   - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-bcmath * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's bcmath extension

my composer.json file as below
"require": {
        "php": "~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 || ~8.2.0",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "shopify/shopify-api": "^5.0",
        "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^5.3",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6"
    }

My php version is 8.2
How to resolve this issue.

Have you first tried apt install bcmath? Composer does not configure PHP on your system - just the PHP interface libraries. The extension must be installed and configured first.

Thank you for the input.
After many attempts to resolve this issue, I discovered my mistake. If you are using a Docker container in your application while deploying on Heroku, you need to ensure that any required PHP extensions are specified in your Dockerfile.
Here’s how you can do it:
Open your Dockerfile.
Add the necessary PHP extensions using the appropriate commands. For example, to install the mysqli extension, you can add:

Dockerfile


RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath


This ensures that the extensions are available in your Docker container when your application is deployed on Heroku.
I hope this helps!
